# How many ways can N objects be split into groups of 3?

Tags: statistics, set-partition

I've found that if there are $N$ objects split up into two groups of $n_1$, and $n_2=N-n_1$ then this can be divided into $$\frac{N!}{n_1!(N-n_1)!}$$ groups.

How can I extend this onto splitting $N$ objects split into three groups of $n_1, n_2, n_3$ if we assume that the objects are distinguishable, where $n_2=N-n_1$ and $n_3=N-n_1-n_2$?

Comment: What have you tried? where do you get stuck? Which methods are you supposed to use or know about which relate to this?

Comment: sorry, I've just added some background on how I'm approaching the problem. I know I can take a recursive approach to handling this problem but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: Look up [Multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) and their combinatorial interpretation.